# "having", "with" or "who have" - which is preferred for an attribute conferring group membership?

Tags: word-choice

I need to provide a label in my software's user interface that describes about the list of members having private access to a document. So which one will suit best from the following?

1. Members having private access
2. Members with private access
3. Members who have private access

Note: The label will be suffixed with a colon.

Comment: I want to upvote Matt Эллен's edit :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my two cents:

It's software, and I'm assuming it's commercial and all that. I would feel it would need to be more of the "formal sort". Products seem to have rather formal and bureaucratic syntax.

That's why, something with fewer words would perhaps be better.

I would say:

> Members with private access

Sounds the most professional.

Answer (score 1):

"With" is not only more formal, but also more succinct, which is a good thing in UI design.  It's good to think in terms of "what is the smallest thing I can put here that correctly and unambiguously conveys my meaning?"

Answer (score 0):

I would go with

> Members with private access

as well. Although if you wanted to head in a more formal direction, you could use it as an attribute that says

> x: private access enabled

Answer (score 0):

As a user of your software I would want to know how these members gained their right of access. So, for example, would you describe them as *Members with access to all documents*, *Members you have granted access to your documents*, or *Members you have granted access to this document*?